# How to add parameters to python decorator

Tags: python, parameters, decorator

I know we can create basic decorator this way :

```py
def printArgs(function):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print(args, kwargs)
        return function(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

class A:
    @printArgs
    def add(self, number1, number2):
        return number1 + number2
```

I would like to create a decorator that take additional arguments like this :

```py
def addXToResult(function, x):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return function(*args, **kwargs) + x
    return wrapper
```

But when I try to use this second decorator, I have the `missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'` appearing:

```py
class A:
    @addXToResult(2)
    def add(self, number1, number2):
        return number1 + number2
```

If I try to change it to `@addXToResult(A.add, 2)` I get `NameError: name 'A' is not defined`.

Why is it that in the first case, the decorated function is passed automatically as parameter (like the self is automatically filled in class method) ?

How am I supposed to create a decorator with additional parameters ?

Comment: You are using the word `annotation`. I think you mean `decorator`.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I got confused over the term to use. It's decorator (and suddenly my Google research return me more pertinent results).